# Positive feedback

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, html

I have a matching game, where a user can drag the answer from the left column to the right.
I'd like to provide some positive feedback to the user with some eye candy.

I'm thinking of the letters on the right-hand side exploding like fireworks, or doing some sort of animation, like running off the screen in a random direction.

You know, fireworks like what happens when you win at Spider-Solitaire.

Comment: "Exploding like fireworks" - this discriminates against users with certain forms of PTSD.

Comment: You'll be better off asking about implementation specifics. This seems to be more of a general design concept question. Not quite right for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not freeze both the letters (into ice cubes) when they are matches - and then have them both drop down and off the screen.  You could then do variants every 5 or 10 matches, like the pair bursting into flames or developing a balloon that carried them up and out of the screen.

Comment: I like it.  Would I use the html5 canvas element for this, or some sort of jQuery plugin?

Comment: The jquery animate plugin will make moving the letters about easy enough, and you can change the background image for a div (say that is wrapped round each letter being animated) so that it can become the ice cube or whatever.